# google directory api retrieve addresses

Tags: asp.net-core, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-directory-api

I got null when I tried to retrieve addresses from directory api

[image: Here]

```
 foreach (var userItem in users)
            {
                
                    employees = new PeopleModel
                    {
                       
                      Addresse = userItem.Addresses[0].Formatted;
                       
                    };
                      employeeslist.Add(employees);
                  }
```

Update

```
DirectoryService service = GetJsonCredential();
        UsersResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.List();
        request.Customer = "my_customer";
        request.MaxResults = 500;
        request.OrderBy = UsersResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.Email;
        request.Projection= UsersResource.ListRequest.ProjectionEnum.Full;
       
         
        IList<User> users = request.Execute().UsersValue;
```

here is calling the service

Comment: did you try adding fields = *

Comment: @DaImTo could you explain more

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code i need to see how you are calling the API then i can show you how to add fields optional parameter

Comment: @DaImTo updated